# Jupyter lab variable Inspector for R not working?

Tags: r, variables, jupyter-lab

I have installed Jupyter lab Variable Inspector but I can not use it with R kernel.

I have also the repr lirabry loaded.

The problem I am facing is that I am able to see the vaiable in the Editor but I can not open it to view the content.

Could you please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Jupyter Lab is a newer application compared to Jupyter Notebook.  Many of the "view" features that are common in libraries do not function in Jupyter Lab.

If you have the RStudio installed, you will probably find the "view" feature of your library will work fine.

Comment: Thank you Gray, this is very useful information for me. There is "just" R installed on the machine where I am working and no RStudio, so no way for me have the "view" feature.